# Fokker-Planck equation from Langevin equation in stochastic inflation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, stochastic-processes

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9407016) by Starobinsky and Yokoyama where they give the coarse-grained equation of motion,
$$
\dot{\bar{\phi}}({\bf x},t ) = -\frac{1}{3H}V'(\bar{\phi}) + f({\bf x},t)
$$
where $f({\bf x},t)$ is given by
$$
f({\bf x},t)
=
\epsilon a(t)H^2
\int\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\delta(k - \epsilon a(t)H)
\left[
a_{\bf k}\phi_{\bf k}(t) e^{-i {\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}
+
a_{\bf k}^\dagger\phi_{\bf k}^*(t) e^{i {\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}
\right].
$$
This equation can be considered to be a Langevin equation for the stochastic quantity $\bar{\phi}$ with a stochastic noise term $f({\bf x},t)$ with correlation properties given by
$$
\left\langle
f({\bf x}_1, t_1) f({\bf x}_2, t_2)
\right\rangle
=
\frac{H^3}{4\pi^2}\delta(t_1 - t_2) j_0(\epsilon a(t)H|{\bf x}_1 - {\bf x}_2|),
\qquad
j_0(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z}.
$$
The authors then write down the Fokker-Planck equation corresponding to this Langevin equation,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho[\bar{\phi}({\bf x},t)]}{\partial t}
=
\frac{1}{3H}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\phi}}
\left\{
V'[\bar{\phi}({\bf x},t)]\rho[\bar{\phi}({\bf x},t)]
\right\}
+
\frac{H^3}{8\pi^2}
\frac{\partial^2 \rho[\bar{\phi}({\bf x},t)]}{\partial \bar{\phi}^2}.
$$

***Question**:* How do you derive this equation?

I've attempted to derive this using the Kramer-Moyel expansion. For a Langevin equation of the form,
$$
\dot{\xi}(t) = h(\xi, t) + g(\xi, t)\Gamma(t)
$$
where,
$$
\left\langle
\Gamma(t)
\right\rangle = 0,
\qquad
\left\langle
\Gamma(t)\Gamma(t')
\right\rangle = 2\delta(t - t')
$$

The corresponding Fokker-Planck equation is given by
$$
\frac{\partial W(\xi,t)}{\partial  t} = 
-\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}[D^{(1)}(\xi,t )W(\xi, t)]
+
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2}[D^{(2)}(\xi,t )W(\xi, t)]
$$
where $D^{(i)}$ are the Kramer-Moyel expansion coefficients (see Risken, The Fokker-Planck Equation) given by,
$$
D^{(1)}(\xi,t) = h(\xi,t) + \frac{\partial g(\xi,t)}{\partial \xi} g(\xi,t),
\qquad
D^{(2)}(\xi,t) = g^2(\xi,t)
$$

However, this result doesn't seem to work because in the problem of interest the stochastic force is dependent on both ${\bf x}$ and $t$. Additionally, the correlation $\left\langle f({\bf x}_1, t_1) f({\bf x}_2, t_2) \right\rangle$ is far more complicated in this case.

Is there a more general formalism that could help with more general force $f({\bf x},t)$?

Any help or resources about this particular derivation would be *greatly* appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of deriving the Fokker-Planck equation, we only need correlation between two different times $t_1$ and $t_2$ for the stochastic force, not for two different spatial locations. In other words, you can set $x_1=x_2 \equiv x$ in the correlation relation when deriving the Fokker-Planck equation. In the paper, the correlation relation is given in that more general form with $x_1$ and $x_2$ for other purposes than for derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation. From setting $x_1=x_2 \equiv x$ in the correlation relation follows $j_0(...)=1$ and thus we are left with a delta-correlation. The Fokker-Planck equation follows directly from the Kramers-Moyal expansion you have written there when you identify $\Gamma=f/\sqrt{H^3/8 \pi^2}$ and $g=\sqrt{H^3/8 \pi^2}$.